# Problem in running Junit tests in eclipse 3.4.1 on Mac OS

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, junit

Problem in running Junit tests in eclipse 3.4.1 on Mac OS

I am getting this error:
'Lanuching AllTests' has encountered a problem. 
Cannot connect to VM.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2009-01-29 10:07:44.047
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.25
4/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using th
e values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.launching 4 120 2009-01-29 10:42:59.295
!MESSAGE Cannot connect to VM
!STACK 0
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:384)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:450)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService.accept(Socket
TransportService.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportImpl.accept(SocketTra
nsportImpl.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketListeningConnectorImpl.accept(
SocketListeningConnectorImpl.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.StandardVMDebugger$ConnectRunnable
.run(StandardVMDebugger.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:613)
```

Comment: More info please...are you trying to run the tests in debug mode?  Are you trying to run some remote tests?  What do your tests do?

Comment: I just run a simple local test:
<pre>
package com.android.hello;

import android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase;


public class TestHelloAndroid extends ActivityUnitTestCase<HelloAndroid>{

 public TestHelloAndroid() {
  super(HelloAndroid.class);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

}
</pre>

Comment: yinglcs: Please provide these information in your question, not in a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did that solved my problem (Eclipse on MacOSX Lion):

- Go to project properties->Java Build Path->Libraries
- Add JRE System Library
- Go to Order and Export tab, move JRE System Library up to top.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This comments saved my ass. Thanks, ADT on Mac with "usual" JUnit-Tests gave me the very same result as the OPs description.

Just adding the JRE as a Library worked just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and JUnit communicate via IPC (Inter Process Communication). Here, you're using android with a specific virtual machine.

The message `System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.25
4/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences` makes me wonder.
There are preferences in your Eclipse and they are probably wrong. Try to remove these nonproxy settings in your Eclipse.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For other folks having this problem but not trying anything related to android within their elcipse/Mac OS X Leopard - in case you are compiling against JRE 1.6 (ie. soylatte's hack release, since Leopards do not naturally support Java 1.6), what has worked for me was to manually remove the fake 1.6 VMs from eclipse and add the real one from Preferences->Java->installed JREs

Good luck!